# Boost up the Batch Processing speed

Tags: windows, string, performance, batch-file, for-loop

I have a log file `Source.txt` with following content-structure :

```
Handle v3.51
Copyright (C) 1997-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataSource.exe pid: 5860 USER\DEVELOPMENT
  5EC: File  (R--)   G:\apps\OracleClient\product\11.1.0\client_2\RDBMS\mesg\ocius.msb
  600: File  (R--)   G:\apps\OracleClient\product\11.1.0\client_2\RDBMS\mesg\ocius.msb
  614: File  (R--)   G:\apps\OracleClient\product\11.1.0\client_2\RDBMS\mesg\ocius.msb
  628: File  (R--)   G:\apps\OracleClient\product\11.1.0\client_2\RDBMS\mesg\ocius.msb
  834: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP1_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Timer.log
  838: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP1_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Debug.log
  854: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP1_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Timer.log
  858: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP1_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Debug.log
  874: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP1_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Timer.log
  878: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP1_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Debug.log
 1058: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_8a1a02152edb659b

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataSource.exe pid: 10568 USER\DEVELOPMENT
 1074: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_88e046c92fae6f57
 1078: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_8a1a02152edb659b
  8F4: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_88e046c92fae6f57
  908: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP2_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Timer.log
  90C: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP2_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Debug.log
  928: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP2_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Timer.log
  92C: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP2_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Debug.log
  948: File  (RW-)   G:\apps\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epmsystem8\products\FinancialManagement\Server Working Folder\APP2_RulesLogFiles\1-28-2014_Timer.log
1064: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_88e046c92fae6f57
 1068: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_8a1a02152edb659b
  | |
  | |
  | |
and so on......
```

I wanted to achieve the followings:

1. Search for the 1st occurrence of 'DataSource.exe' and then search
   for 1st occurrence of any one of the word among `(APP1 APP2 APP3 APP4
   APP5 APP6 APP7 APP8 APP9)` and let's assume APP1 word found then
   send the following output to a file 'Output.txt' :

   ```
   DataSource.exe pid: 5860 USER\DEVELOPMENT  APP1
   ```
2. Then search for 2nd occurrence of 'DataSource.exe' and then
       search again for 1st occurrence of any one of the word among `(APP1
       APP2 APP3 APP4 APP5 APP6 APP7 APP8 APP9)`[We can discard the word which is already being found] and let's assume APP2 word
       found then append the following output to the same file 'Output.txt' :

   ```
   DataSource.exe pid: 10568 USER\DEVELOPMENT  APP2
   ```

   and so on..

I am using below working script:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "keystring1="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  Source.txt
  ) DO (
  ECHO %%a|FIND "DataSource.exe" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET keystring1=%%a
  FOR %%b IN (APP1 APP2 APP3 APP4 APP5 APP6 APP7 APP8 APP9 ) DO (
   ECHO %%a|FIND "%%b" >NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF DEFINED keystring1 CALL ECHO(%%keystring1%% %%b&SET "keystring1="

  )))>Output.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

**Problem:**

The problem I'm experiencing here is for a `Source.txt file of size 312 KB` , This script is taking `4 minutes to produce Output.txt` even for only those 9 APPs, which seems to be quite large time.

I want to reduce this time anyhow, without using any extra batch file. any workaround please ?

*Exact application names are different from APP1, APP2...etc.

Comment: Instead of search the process and then determine what files has it open, enumerate the files (`dir`) and for each of them determine the process that has it locked (`handle file`)

Answer (score 0):

Your secondary search might be taking some time - where `%%a` is being checked against `APP1.. APP2.. etc.` You could create a second batch file to call this file with different parameters, running them in parallel.

If your script is called `script.bat`, create a second script that does the following -

```
START script.bat APP1 APP2 APP3
START script.bat APP4 APP5 APP6
START script.bat APP7 APP8 APP9
```

Then change your script to include the input parameters.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "searchvals=%*"
SET "keystring1="
(
    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (Source.txt) DO (
        ECHO %%a|FIND "DataSource.exe" >NUL
        IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET keystring1=%%a
        FOR %%b IN (%searchvals%) DO (
            ECHO %%a|FIND "%%b" >NUL
            IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF DEFINED keystring1 CALL ECHO(%%keystring1%% %%b&SET "keystring1="
)))>Output.txt

EXIT
```

This way each instance of the script is only comparing each line of `Source.txt` against three strings, as opposed to 9.

Hopefully this actually does help. Note that the content of `Output.txt` probably won't be in order.

Comment: @unclement..This is a realy good solution, but unfortunately, i'm restricted to create any other batch file. I have to achieve the things in a single batch script only.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (APP1 APP2 APP3 APP4 APP5 APP6 APP7 APP8 APP9 ) do (
type "source.txt" |findrepl "DataSource.exe" /e:"^-----" /b:"%%a" |findrepl /o:1:1  2>nul
)
pause
```

Comment: @foxi..perfect helper file is that..realy..! but i am not allowed to use any other batch file. i have to achieve the things in a single batch file only...any help, please ?

Comment: As a matter of interest, what speed improvement do you get from this solution, Sunny?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "tokens=1-5* delims=\ " %%a in ('findstr "DataSource.exe APP" Source.txt') do (
   if "%%a" equ "DataSource.exe" (
      set pid=%%a %%b %%c %%d\%%e
      set "APP="
   ) else if not defined APP (
      set "APP=%%f"
      set "APP=!APP:*APP=!"
      echo !pid!  APP!APP:~0,1!
   )
)) > Output.txt

goto :EOF
```

Comment: @Aacini..you would also be agree with me that we have to be more generalised as my prime concern with increasing speed is related with that in future more applications with different names can be easily added.